# removing pound sign from a variable webscraped in Python

Tags: python, css-selectors, webdriver

I'm using selenium web driver to web scrape a price and what to do some maths with it. Only issue is that it still has the £ sign and python is treating it as a single 'thing'. I would like to remove the £ sign and then have the variable as a float. Thanks in advance.

Say for example the price its scraping is £32.48. It returns that price so the css selector is working, but when i find the length of that variable it returns 1 (rather then 6) and when I print price[0] I get the whole thing not just the £ sign.

```
emai = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#price00_scost')
price = emai.text
print(price)
length = len(price)
print(price[0])
print(length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a `list` of `string`, that's why when you print `len(price)` you get `1`. `price[0]` is the string at first index (only string in this case) so it's length is `6`. To get the value as a float use

```
euro = float(price[0][1:])
print(euro) # prints 32.48
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are getting a list in return instead of string.
If you print your price variable the output will be list with just one element.